# How do I run a global search in DOORS?

Tags: ibm-doors

## Background

I am trying to search for specific a specific string of text that I know exists in multiple modules. However, I forget all the modules that contain this text.

## Question

Does DOORS have a global search function? That is, can it search for text that exists in multiple modules as opposed to the current selected module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools->Find.
Though this only looks in Object Text and Object Heading of each module.

Answer (score 1):

Also, there is a "global search utility tool" available at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014289994

Note that the last lines of the script have been garbled. The script must end like this:

```
if (fillModsList(GSUModList) == 0) {
    insert(GSUModList, 0, "(No modules)")
}
show GSUBox, "(No modules)"
```